# Does the keyword "shared" prevent race conditions?

Tags: c++, openmp, atomic

I'm unclear what "shared" does in openMP.  I see that the [spec](http://www.openmp.org/mp-documents/OpenMP3.0-SummarySpec.pdf) states that shared "declares one or more list items to be shared by tasks..." but that seems unclear to me.

For example, if I have the following code:

```
    #pragma omp parallel for shared(num1)
    for(i=0; i<m; i++) {
        for(j=0; j < n; j++) {
            if(myFunc(i,j) < 0) {
                num1 += 256*u(i,j);
            }
        }
    }
```

Will this stop race conditions with num1 and give an accurate result at the end of this for loop?  If not, what exactly does it do?

Answer (score 0):

> Will this stop race conditions?

No, It [won't](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/openMP/#SHARED):

> It is the programmer's responsibility to ensure that multiple threads properly access SHARED variables (such as via CRITICAL sections)

Shared section just make the same variable visible from multiple threads.

You can use critical sections or atomic access for syncronization, but in *this* case you'd better use [reduction](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/openMP/#REDUCTION) clause:

```
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:num1)
```

Comment: I still don't get what shared does.  Aren't the variables already visible by the multiple threads?  Don't they share memory?